# React Native unlink library from iOS or android only

Tags: ios, react-native

I had searched throughout SO and just found about react-native unlink only. What i want is unlink a library in specific platform such as android or ios. By running react-native unlink will unlink all native dependencies in both android and ios platform, this is not what i'm looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I had found an answer,

```
react-native unlink react-native-config --platforms=ios
```

or:

```
react-native unlink react-native-config --platforms=android
```